# Remote Access of Tomcat service

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, remote-debugging, tomcat8

I want to deploy remotely from a windows server to another windows server where I need to start and stop the tomcat service remotely.
But I'm unable to access the service (start or stop the service), The tomcat service is configured in Task Scheduler and I want to run the Tomcat through command within a Batch script. When I'm running the command In the particular server where I want to deploy It's working fine, but remotely the command cudn't access the Tomcat service. Please assist me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run/modify/etc.. scheduled task remotly with `schtasks` command.

[Microsoft schtasks command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766428(v=ws.11).aspx)

`schtasks /run /s <machine name> /tn <task name>`

Command console help

```
`C:\>schtasks /?`

SCHTASKS /parameter [arguments]

Description:
    Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run and
    end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system. Replaces AT.exe.

Parameter List:
    /Create         Creates a new scheduled task.

    /Delete         Deletes the scheduled task(s).

    /Query          Displays all scheduled tasks.

    /Change         Changes the properties of scheduled task.

    /Run            Runs the scheduled task immediately.

    /End            Stops the currently running scheduled task.

    /?              Displays this help message.

Examples:
    SCHTASKS
    SCHTASKS /?
    SCHTASKS /Run /?
    SCHTASKS /End /?
    SCHTASKS /Create /?
    SCHTASKS /Delete /?
    SCHTASKS /Query  /?
    SCHTASKS /Change /?
```

Your post is lack of info. Can you be more specific with your problem?

Hope the command below helps.

Comment: I had tried with all dis.. The command i used is: ** runas /noprofile /user:Administrator /savecred "schtasks /Run /S localhost /U <username >/P <password># /TN StartTomcat" ** When I, running the same from the server in which i want ti deploy it's working fine.. But remotely(from another server) the command cannot initiate the process  to another server.

Comment: Have you check permissions?Do you have a user to run this kind of things?Do you have th rights on the machine?We have a user (service user) with nearly admin rights and no login interface activated and all the task and services holds on this user. The user is created in all of infrastructure servers to that kind of things.
Hope this helps.